# Gson slow in Android Studio debugger

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, gson

I find that Gson deserialization is often extremely slow (e.g. several seconds) when I step over it from a breakpoint in Android Studio. If the same code is executed while in the debugger, but not while manually stepping over it, it runs in 'normal' time (e.g. a few milliseconds).

I haven't experienced this with any other code, and it doesn't appear to matter what I'm deserializing, or how small or large the Json is.

My Gson version is 2.3.1

Has anyone else experienced this, or know of any way of fixing it?

Comment: BTW, I haven't done any Android development in the last 6 months or so, but I just fired up Android Studio 2.1.2 and created a new project with Gson 2.7 and buildToolsVersion "23.0.2". The slowness does not happen with this project. I'm still not sure what the issue was, but it seems to be solved, at least for a small, simple case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite normal. I face it all the time with `Gson` usually instead of `Step Over`(F8 on OSX) if you put two break point just before and after deserialization LOC and use `Resume Program`(Option + Cmd + R on OSX) instead it works fine.

Comment: This answer doesn't point to an actual fix, but I did ask for a work-around, and while obvious, this technically qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Debug view, click on the two red circles icon (View and manage all breakpoints and watchpoints), delete **all** breakpoints, run the app again, and re-add whatever breakpoints you need.